# Run code every second device shakes

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I'm trying to perform some code every second the iPhone is shaking right and left. [Here's a link](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/cmdm-gravity.gif) to a .gif to illustrate the kind of rotation I want. I tried the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
    manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) in
        println("he")
    }
}
```

When I run the app (I'm working with the simulator,) and go to "Hardware > Rotate Left / Rotate Right / Shake Gesture, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Testing code that requires something like shaking really should be done on an actual iOS device.

Comment: well! why don't you put breakpoint into your code to monitor what happen? Generally, testing code that applied CoreMotion should be done with real iDevices. By fully support of sensor on device, it can help you to invest what happen in your code